# Mozilla firefox debugger not working

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox

When debugger is enabled in firefox by pressing F12 it is disabling the editing feature in the website for which debugger is opened for. Firefox version is 58.0.1

Answer (score 6):

The new UI of firefox is having some problems for me. Once I open the debugger UI cannot do any operations on the web page. Hence went back to old UI by setting the below property to false in browser.

Go to firefox browser. In the address bar type, "about:config". Without the quotes. Search for the below property and toggle it. The value can be toggled(changed) by right clicking or by just clicking on the entry. Set this property to false which takes back to old UI.

property to be altered ==> devtools.debugger.new-debugger-frontend

Comment: Great! it works for me. Just change the "devtools.debugger.new-debugger-frontend" to false.

Comment: I don't have this setting in version 66.0 (64-bit)

Comment: Does seem to be missing in recent builds - debugger was broken for me until I went to "about:support" and used the "Refresh Firefo" function

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to fix any error is to reset your Firefox under `about:support`. Lookut for somethin like clean or refresh or reset